# Set DateTimePicker element via AutomationElement

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, ui-automation, automationelement

I want to be able to set a `DateTimePicker` element to a certain time via `AutomationElement`. It stores the time as "hh:mm:ss tt" (i.e. 10:45:56 PM).

I get the element as such:

`ValuePattern p = AECollection[index].GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;`

I believe I have two options:

`p.SetValue("9:41:22 AM");`

or

`p.Current.Value = "9:41:22 AM";`

However, the first option simply doesn't work (I read somewhere that this may be broken in .NET 2.0?, I am using .NET 3.0 though). The second option tells me that the element is read only, how can I change the status so that it is not read only? Or more simply, how can I change the time :( ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the native window handle and send `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME` message to set the selected date for `DateTimePicker` control.

To do so, I suppose you have found the element, then you can use follwing code:

```
var date =  new DateTime(1998, 1, 1);
DateTimePickerHelper.SetDate((IntPtr)element.Current.NativeWindowHandle, date);
```

**DateTimePickerHelper**

Here is the source code for `DateTimePickerHelper`. The class has a public static `SetDate` method which allow you to set a date for the date time picker control:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class DateTimePickerHelper {
    const int GDT_VALID = 0;
    const int DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME = (0x1000 + 2);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    struct SYSTEMTIME {
        public short wYear;
        public short wMonth;
        public short wDayOfWeek;
        public short wDay;
        public short wHour;
        public short wMinute;
        public short wSecond;
        public short wMilliseconds;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, 
        int wParam, SYSTEMTIME lParam);
    public static void SetDate(IntPtr handle, DateTime date) {
        var value = new SYSTEMTIME() {
            wYear = (short)date.Year,
            wMonth = (short)date.Month,
            wDayOfWeek = (short)date.DayOfWeek,
            wDay = (short)date.Day,
            wHour = (short)date.Hour,
            wMinute = (short)date.Minute,
            wSecond = (short)date.Second,
            wMilliseconds = 0
        };
        SendMessage(handle, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, 0, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we have any solution for wpf xaml framework?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for Wpf based app

```
object patternObj = AECollection[index].GetCurrentPattern(UIA.UIA_PatternIds.UIA_ValuePatternId);
if (patternObj != null) {
 (UIA.IUIAutomationValuePattern)patternObj.SetValue(itemVal);
}
```